# random css animation on hover

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have javascript that when hover plays an animation, but i have 4 different animations and i would like it to randomize it each time the element is hovered over

here's my code

```
function firsthelp() { 

document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter your first name';
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation ='greenhover 2s;';
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.WebkitAnimation ='greenhover 2s';


}
```

The other css animations are `bluehover` `orangehover` and `purplehover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function getRandomAnimation(duration) {

      var possibleAnimations = ["greenhover","bluehover","orangehover","purplehover"];
      var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4));
      return (possibleAnimations[randomNumber] + " " + duration || "");
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation = getRandomAnimation('2s)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.random](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) to randomize your animations

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var hover;
if(randomNumber == 1)
{
    hover = 'greenhover'
}
else if(randomNumber == 2)
{
    hover = 'purplehover';        
}
else if(randomNumber == 3)
{
    hover = 'orangehover';        
}
else if(randomNumber == 4)
{
    hover = 'bluehover';        
}

document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter your first name';
document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation =hover +' 2s;';
document.getElementById('help-box').style.WebkitAnimation =hover +' 2s';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function firsthelp() { 

document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter your first name';
  var random_animation = ["greenhover", "bluehover", "orangehover", "purplehover"];
  var number = Math.random();
  var animation = random_animation[Math.floor(number * 4)] + " 2s";
  document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation = animation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Random` to get random no between 1 to 4 or either 0 to 3. Here I am getting between 0 to 3 and using a JavaScript array to get the animation

```
var animations = new Array();
animations[0] = "greenhover";
animations[1] = "bluehover";
animations[2] = "orangehover";
animations[3] = "purplehover";

var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

document.getElementById('help-text').innerHTML = 'Enter your first name';
document.getElementById('help-box').style.animation =animations[randomNo] +' 2s;';
document.getElementById('help-box').style.WebkitAnimation =animations[randomNo]+' 2s';
```